# UITableViewController not populating data in swift. AnyObject is not convertible to String

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am completely new to swift and I am pretty find it difficult to find that its quite different than obj.C
I have a difficulty while populating the table view.

my coding to populate goes as follows -

```
class DetailTableViewController: UITableViewController
{

var items = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      items=["dodnf","dgfd"]
        Item()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }


    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return items.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellreuse", forIndexPath: indexPath)



      cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.item]

        return cell
    }
```

When I am writing the following code   `cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.item]` I am getting an error message as- `AnyObject is not convertible to String`

So what is my error and why is it so?

Comment: Simply follow the suggestion and write items[indexPath.item] as! String .

Comment: @Matte.Car So what is the problem I am having.  Why was it showing so. Still its displaying the comments but showing " Treating a forced downcast to 'String' as optional will never produce 'nil' "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the type when declaring the data source array:

```
var items : [String] = []
```

That's all. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` the compiler can infer the type.

However the proper syntax is supposed to be

```
cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have declared `items` as an array without specifying the type of the elements (`var items = []`). Therefore, when you try to get an element from the array, the compiler errors because it cannot guarantee the type of the element is what you are expecting.

You need to **specify the type of the items in the array**. You can do this in either one of the two possible stages:

- when you **declare the array** (**preferred** to leverage Swift's type safety):

  ```
  var items = [String]() // or its equivalent: var items : [String] = []

  // Alternatively, if you know it at the time of declaration you can just do the following and let
  // Swift's type inference do its work
  var items = ["dodnf","dgfd"]
  ```
- OR when you **get an element** from the array:

  ```
   cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.item] as? String
  ```

You can learn more about **Collection Types** in Swift in [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID107).

Comment: `items` is definitely a non optional array of `String`. There's no reason at all to use `as?`

Comment: … neither `as!`, there is no optional at all and the compiler knows the type.

Comment: @vadian Thanks for you comment. About `as?` or `as!`, you need to do it if you don't do the first option. I am just trying to expose both ways, although the first one is clearly the one that makes more sense in this example.

Comment: @vadian Yes, I agree, that is yet another reason on why the first option is the preferred one. I believe it is quite clear in my answer which one is the best practice and which one is not. Still, I believe on learning best practices and understanding why they are preferred (for which you need to know the other options), instead of just knowing the preferred way by heart.

Comment: I got that error that if you are not mentioning the array type then the compiler takes it as "ANY OBJECT